# C# WPF Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

Could someone recommend a good tutorial for drag and drop.

The basics are easy to find, but they don't help me much achieve the goal I need. In a nutshell, I need two main panels, left one will contain multiple stack panels (each of them will have horizontal orientation). The right one will contain objects I want to drag and drop onto the panels to the left. What I want to achieve is, once I release object, I want it to become part of the panel so it 'flows' with other objects in that panel. Also, I want it to detect if I am in between two already existing object, so it is placed between them, moving the right ones by one position. Reverse operation should also be possible

Thanks for help

Comment: That is very specific and you are unlikely to find anything like that.  If you understand the basic concepts well enough, you should be able to extrapolate to complete you task -- that is the job of a developer after all.

Answer (score 1):

I have some code that I have taken out of an old project which you can use to achieve the drag and drop behaviour. It uses two list boxes, both with AllowDrop enabled and some events to handle the dragging.

The test data:

```
var itemsInGroup1 = new ObservableCollection<MoveableItem>()
        {
            new MoveableItem {ID = 1, Name = "Item 1"},
            new MoveableItem {ID = 2, Name = "Item 2"},
            new MoveableItem {ID = 3, Name = "Item 3"},
        };

        var itemsInGroup2 = new ObservableCollection<MoveableItem>()
        {
            new MoveableItem {ID = 4, Name = "Item 4"},
            new MoveableItem {ID = 5, Name = "Item 5"},
            new MoveableItem {ID = 6, Name = "Item 6"},
        };

        List1.ItemsSource = itemsInGroup1;
        List2.ItemsSource = itemsInGroup2;
```

The ListBox:

```
<ListBox
        x:Name="List2"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Margin="30"
        AllowDrop="True"
        BorderBrush="DarkBlue"
        BorderThickness="2"
        Drop="List_OnDrop"
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="List_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

You capture the DragSource using PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown

```
public ListBox DragSource { get; set; }

private void List_OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBox = (ListBox) sender;
        if (listBox == null) return;

        DragSource = listBox;

        object data = GetDataFromListBox(DragSource, e.GetPosition(listBox));
        if (data != null)
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, data, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
```

The data is obtained from the ListBox by using a hit test on the location that you have clicked.

```
private static object GetDataFromListBox(ListBox source, Point point)
    {
        if (source.InputHitTest(point) is UIElement element)
        {
            object data = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            while (data == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                data = source.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(element);
                element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;

                if (element == source)
                    return null;

                if (data != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                    return data;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Finally, in the drop event you remove the item from the source and place it in the target.

```
private void List_OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var target = (ListBox) sender;
        if (target.Name == DragSource.Name) return;

        var data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(MoveableItem));

        ((IList) DragSource.ItemsSource).Remove(data);
        ((IList) target.ItemsSource).Add(data);
    }
```

I have not addressed your issue of detection between objects as the codebase I extracted this from did not require that functionality. You can build this in yourself by subscribing to DragOver on the ItemTemplate, figuring out which items the drag is currently between and then re-ordering the collection after it is dropped in.

More here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/drag-and-drop-overview

Edit: I found the original article - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/drag-and-drop-item-in-listbox-in-wpf/